# Is there an easy way to create a drop event in a running GUI app from the shell?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, desktop, drag-and-drop

Normally, I work in a terminal in a desktop window. I chat with co-workers in Slack, which is a GUI only app. I can share files by dragging and dropping them from Nautilus, but it would be nice if I didn't have to open Nautilus at all.

If I have a path for a file, and the PID of an app that can handle drop events, is there a command that can send a drop event to the app? I'm hoping for a workflow like:

```
find ~/Pictures -name lol.gif | xargs gnome-drop --pid 29058
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing just the PID is not enough; even if you assume X11 (no Wayland), a program might still have several windows open. And even windows aren't drop targets – individual widgets are.

(Though, AFAIK, the X11 messages just deal with coordinates, only the program itself translates them to a specific widget internally.)

So such a tool might exist, but instead of the PID you'd give it a window name and (at minimum) some pixel coordinates. Perhaps it could use AT-SPI to divine the right widget.

I haven't seen any such program yet. However, [Dragbox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137916/2168) might suit your purposes – it's easy enough to launch from a terminal.

---

- [Drag-and-Drop Protocol for the X Window System](http://jjlindal.net/jafl/xdnd/) (XDnD, the current protocol)
- [Motif Programming Manual: Chapter 22](http://www.ist.co.uk/motif/books/vol6A/ch-22.fm.html) (Motif DnD, the obsolete protocol)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137905/can-i-drag-a-file-into-a-window-without-a-file-manager

Comment: Dragbox wins! Now I feel a little silly for crafting clever `find | grep | xarg dragbox` pipes, but then having to reach for the mouse and drag the little boxes over from one window to the other, like a well trained monkey :p